# JS object property which name contain several spaces in between?

Tags: javascript

Well, I've just seen this in a code developed by a friend:

```
var zeroCounter= value.countDown["Span O2/Zero CO/NOX/SO2/CO2"].counter
```

How can `Span O2/Zero CO/NOX/SO2/CO2` be a property? (It is being accessed using object notation syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) you can have the key as anything as long as it is a String or Symbol:

```js
let value = {
  countDown: {
    "Span O2/Zero CO/NOX/SO2/CO2": {
      counter: 10
    }
  }
}

var zeroCounter = value.countDown["Span O2/Zero CO/NOX/SO2/CO2"].counter;

console.log(zeroCounter); // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket syntax to access props with spaces in them. Perfectly acceptable, but you can only use bracket syntax to access them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects